# How to access a class variable from another class in python?

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I have the following code segment :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 'CHAT'

    def method1(self):
        self.state = 'SEND'

    def printer(self):
        print self.state


class B(A):
    def method2(self):
        self.method1()
        print self.state

ob_B = B()
ob_A = A()
ob_B.method2()
ob_A.printer()
```

This gives me the output :

```
SEND
CHAT
```

I want it to print :

```
SEND
SEND
```

That is, when `B.method2` is modifying self.state by calling self.method1, I want it to modify the already existing value of `self.state = 'CHAT'` in A's instance. How can I do this?

Comment: You have *instance* attributes, and those are specific to the instances. You are not actually calling `ob_B.method2`.

Comment: That is my problem. I want self.state to be a class variable, and then have it initialized when an object of A is created.

Comment: @segfolt thanks for the edit. missing out () was a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instance is passed as the first argument to each of your methods, so `self` is the instance. You are setting instance attributes and not class variables.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        A.state = 'CHAT'

    def method1(self):
        A.state = 'SEND'

    def printer(self):
        print A.state


class B(A):
    def method2(self):
        self.method1()
        print B.state

ob_B = B()
ob_A = A()
ob_B.method2()
ob_A.printer()
```

---

```
SEND
SEND
```

Comment: Thanks. This does it nicely. :)
But just being inquisitive, say self.state **is** an instance variable. Is their a way to access it from class B?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta Yes, it's part of the instance so it doesn't matter which class you are in unless you have overridden it in `B`, you just access it like `self.x`,

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_B = B()
ob_A = A()
ob_B.method2()
ob_A.printer()
```

You need to call ob_B.method2() -- without the parentheses that statement is just a reference to the function and doesn't actually call it.

Comment: That doesn't change anything to the current problem.

Comment: Don't worry that was just a typo, his output matches up when you fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can call the printer() method by using object of B so that you will get the updated value.

```
ob_B = B()
ob_A = A()
ob_B.method2()
ob_B.printer()
```